# Check if asset exists or return a generic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to check if an image is available and if not to return a generic image. I was hoping that this code would do the trick but it is telling me the method doesn't exist

Controller

```
@products = Supplier
                    .joins(:variants)
                    .joins('INNER JOIN products on products.id = variants.product_id')
                    .where('suppliers.id = ?', params[:id])
                    .group('suppliers.id','products.id','products.name')
                    .pluck('suppliers.id as supplier_id','products.id as prod_id','products.name as prod_name')
```

View

```
- @products.each_with_index do |product, i|
  .product-list.grid-block
    .small-8.grid-content.text-center
      %h4= product[1].titlecase
      - @sizes.each do |size|
        - if size[0] == product[0]
          = link_to size[1], product_path(product[0]), class: 'hollow button tiny'
          %small= number_to_currency(size[2])
    .small-4
      = link_to product_path(product, supplier_id: @supplier), title: product[1] do
        = product[1].image_available
```

Model

```
def image_available(product)
    (Rails.application.assets.find_asset("products/#{product.downcase.tr(' ', '-')}.jpg").nil?) ?
        ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag('products/generic.jpg', size: '50', alt: product.titlecase, title: product.titlecase) :
        ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("products/#{product.downcase.tr(' ', '-')}.jpg", size: '50', alt: product.titlecase, title: product.titlecase)
  end
```

Error Log

```
Started GET "/suppliers/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-06 20:31:53 +1100
Processing by SuppliersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Supplier Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "suppliers".* FROM "suppliers" WHERE "suppliers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (1.3ms)  SELECT products.id as prod_id, products.name as prod_name FROM "suppliers" INNER JOIN "variant_suppliers" ON "variant_suppliers"."supplier_id" = "suppliers"."id" INNER JOIN "variants" ON "variants"."id" = "variant_suppliers"."variant_id" INNER JOIN products on products.id = variants.product_id WHERE (suppliers.id = '1') GROUP BY products.id, products.name
   (2.8ms)  SELECT products.id as prod_id, LEFT(variant_properties.description,1) as short_desc, variants.price as price FROM "suppliers" INNER JOIN "variant_suppliers" ON "variant_suppliers"."supplier_id" = "suppliers"."id" INNER JOIN variants on variants.id = variant_suppliers.variant_id INNER JOIN products on products.id = variants.product_id INNER JOIN variant_properties on variant_properties.variant_id = variants.id INNER JOIN properties on properties.id = variant_properties.property_id AND properties.display_name ='Size' WHERE (suppliers.id = '1')
  Rendered suppliers/show.html.haml within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 74ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `image_available' for "Bubble Tea":String:
  app/views/suppliers/show.html.haml:12:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_suppliers_show_html_haml___1626246587383268315_70147714796320'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:368:in `block in capture_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:608:in `with_haml_buffer'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers.rb:364:in `capture_haml'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/xss_mods.rb:61:in `capture_haml_with_haml_xss'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:45:in `capture_with_haml'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb:106:in `content_tag'
  haml (4.0.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:69:in `content_tag_with_haml'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:184:in `link_to'
  app/views/suppliers/show.html.haml:11:in `block in _app_views_suppliers_show_html_haml___1626246587383268315_70147714796320'
  app/views/suppliers/show.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_suppliers_show_html_haml___1626246587383268315_70147714796320'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/paulmcguane/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  bullet (4.14.10) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.4) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
  puma (2.15.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/e4e72c26f6073831/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-06 20:31:54 +1100
```

Comment: It's telling you what method doesn't exist? Is there an error? Let's see the backtrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're applying the method to `product[1]` not to `product`.  `product[1]` is a string and you don't have that method defined for the `String` class.

There are other issues with the code as well.... you specify the method is "in the Model" but you don't explicitly say which model.  You pass an argument to the method `(product)` but you don't pass an argument when you actually use it in the view.

You may actually want to call it something like...

```
= product.image_available[product.prod_name]
```